# Karma: System notifications when tests pass or fail

Tags: testing, karma-runner

Currently, when using karma/testacular, I open up a command line windows and do `karma start`.  I then generally work in vim, and if I'm working in fullscreen mode I have to tab back to the command window to see the test results when I make changes and save.

I'd like instead to get a system notification showing me if the results of the tests were SUCCESS or FAILURE, each time I save.

Since I work on both linux and windows, I'd like solutions for both cases.  A vim plugin instead of a system notification would also be a fine solution, though I haven't been able to find any yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Karma supports Growl/GNTP as a reporter, looks like this could work in [Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/gntp.aspx) and [Linux](http://karmanebula.com/technically-borked/2012/1/1/install-growl-for-linux-and-gntp-send-on-ubuntu-1110.html).

I did the following which worked on OSX:

1. Installed [Growl](http://growl.info/)
2. Installed [growly](https://github.com/theabraham/growly)

   ```
   npm install growly
   ```
3. Added growl to [karma.conf.js](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html)

   ```
   reporters = ['progress', 'growl'];
   ```

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible on linux? I installed the gorwl-for-linux package in my package manager (pacman on arch), did 'npm install growly' in my project, and added growl to the karma conf, but it's still not working. I just get `WARN [reporter]: No running verion of GNTP found.` Any ideas?

Comment: -_- Nevermind. I didn't start the `gol` (growl on linux) daemon. Set that up to start on boot and works beautifully. Thanks for unknowingly pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5):

Another option if you're using Mountain Lion and OSX Notifications and you don't want to install Growl is to just use the [karma-osx-reporter plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/karma-osx-reporter). Works beautifully!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra in this case, I don't really see what else there is to add. The answer is to use the linked lib. If the link stops working, the answer is no longer useful. Copying the README instructions here won't help.

Comment: You don't happen to know what happens when someone using not Mountain Lion uses this?